# PHP not running on local machine

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'me trying to use the in built web server on my iMac for testing my websites. PHP is not running for some reason. I've checked my httpd.conf file and the following line:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

is uncommented. The following version is installed:

```
PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 24 2012 17:45:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

When I tried to access a PHP page in the browser it just outputs the actual PHP code.

Any help appreciated, I've been Googling this for a few hours and I'm not getting anywhere.

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your web server confg file for this line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```